# Want to export private key in the file system

Tags: powershell, certificate, window, x509certificate

I want to export private key and csr to filesystem.

Using New-Object -ComObject X509Enrollment.CX509PrivateKey to create new private key and using
New-Object -ComObject X509Enrollment.CX509CertificateRequestPkcs10 to create new csr.

I am using powershell to generate csr and private key.

Is there any way to export just privatekey and csr in filesystem rather than exporting it as pfx file combined ?

I don't want to install openssl to achieve this, is there any other poweshell module which will provide this capability other than pspki.

Comment: The keys are strings and you can save the string to a file using any save file method in PS.